# How to set SMOTE parameters in R package DMwR?

Tags: r, outliers, unbalanced-classes

For different imbalanced data-sets which rare class' proportion differ from 30% (rare) to 5% (rare), what is the best way to define the `Perc.Over` and `Perc.Under` in `SMOTE` method of `DMwR`?

Currently I'm using this formula:

```
Over = ( (0.6 * COMMON_NO) - RARE_NO ) / RARE_NO

Under = (0.4 * COMMON_NO) / (RARE_NO * Over)
```

and finally transform it to percentage proportion:

```
Over_Perc = round(Over, 1) * 100

Under_Perc = round(Under, 1) * 100
```

and then feed it to SMOTE as following:

```
newData <- SMOTE(Label ~., df, perc.over=Over_Perc, perc.under=Under_Perc)
```

The thing is that, if the there is 30% rare data in the training set, performing classification without `SMOTE` gives a better performance than using `SMOTE`!
While by having 5%-20% of rare data in the training set, using `SMOTE`, the classification algorithm gives a much more better performance,

p.s. I'm using Matthew's correlation and AUC for performance measurement.

Comment: You're talking about the SMOTE *function* in the *R package* DMwR? It would be better to be more explicit, including in your title.

Comment: @Glen_b The title edited to be more explicit, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be surprised if you did see improvement when you had 30% 'rare' data in the training set. 30% isn't really all that rare in the context of machine learning. What you could do is cross validate with various levels of synthetic data to determine what's giving you the best accuracy on your hold-out data (pretty standard approach to parameter tuning) and then go with that for your final model build. But I would be very surprised based upon personal experience if you saw significant gains in accuracy when you SMOTE past 20-25% positive class instances in your training set.